# Missing components and assets in vite@2 build

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, rollup, vite

I was being able to do a functional build with vite@1 and now that I have updated my configuration and my modules to work with vite@2, some assets and components do not load correctly and have paths that do not correspond to the real absolute paths.

It works perfect on dev and although I am making an app with electron, it should not be a problem since as I mentioned before the builds were good with vite@1.

It is not a problem with the assets, they exist in the build folder. Seems to be a problem when they are required.

#### This is a more detailed issue where you can find all the error messages and screenshots:

https://github.com/MangoTsing/vite-electron-quick/issues/11

> Although I don't think it has to do with electron, again. Still I put it on vite-electron-quick to rule out the possibility.

**This is my vite config**:

```js
import { join } from 'path'
import { UserConfig } from 'vite'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

dotenv.config({ path: join(__dirname, '.env') })
const root = join(__dirname, 'src/render')

const config: UserConfig = {
  root,
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '/@/': root,
    }
  },
  base: './',
  build: {
    outDir: join('../../dist/render'),
    emptyOutDir: true,
    assetsInlineLimit: 0
  },
  server: {
    port: +process.env.PORT,
  },
  plugins: [
    vue()
  ],
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: [
      'electron-is-dev',
      'electron-store',
    ]
  },
}

export default config
```

### Reproduction

https://github.com/denyncrawford/mismor-guillotine

### System Info

- `vite` latest:
- Operating System: Windows 10 2004
- Node version: 15.2.0
- Package manager (npm) and version: 7.0.8

Comment: Did you find why ?

Comment: Yup, sorry, I'll leave an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! This was happening because vue-router's `createWebHistory()` can't hanlde the navigation if the app is not being served. It works on dev mode because vite serves the app but when you build and open the file in a browser it doesn't. So you may say: ***It is pretty basic***, well no... The actual problem was being caused because by the drastical change that vite had at vite@2 and the way the starter-code-templates had to adapt to it. I was using vite with electron, so migrating the starter I'm using was kinda a blinded run. I found that the starter is not serving the file anymore but loading the file directly on the electron `main.js`, so because I don't know why this is for, I did not serve the file again, instead changed to `createWebHashHistory()` at my router config and then it worked!

Comment: Thanks ! That actually helped